# variable declaration gives an error

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in PHP and below is a script which I'm just digging out how the `strlen` and `substr` works but it give me this error:

Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\simul\index.php on line 2

```
<?php
 var $cols;
 var $from;
 var $key;
 var $value;
 var $operand;
 $query = "SELECT {$cols} FROM `{$from}` WHERE `{$key}` = '{$value}' {$operand} ";
 $rest = substr($query, 0, -(strlen($operand)+2)); 
 echo $rest;
 ?>
```

Regards
Programmer

Comment: Where did you read that variables are declared and that they need `var` keyword? They don't.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging a script.

Comment: you dont need a var keyword in php code !! var is used in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has no command for declaring a variable.

A variable is created the moment you first assign a value to it:

`var $cols;` is used when you declare a variable inside a class

Comment: `var` __was__ used rather than __is__ used; this is PHP4 rather than the public/private/protected visibility of PHP5 OOP

Answer (score 3):

```
var $cols;
```

You don't need a `var`, just write `$cols = 0;` or `$cols = NULL;` for example